# Tacking userID through campaigns in GA

Tags: google-analytics

I need to track those users Id whose are coming via campaign, adgroup, keywords in Google Analytics. So, is it possible to track those USERID? If yes, could you please then suggest me how can I achieve?

I've created a custom report in GA but it shows 0 clicks. Ideally, I would like to see the clicks (that which user clicked on what campaign and so on)

Comment: put it in a custom dimension?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is already in place in Google Analytics.

If you go to Acquisition -> All Traffic -> Channels, you'll see a report breaking down sessions by their source type. You can change the primary dimension of the report to display Medium, Ad Content, Campaign, Keyword etc.

If what you want is the same report, but using Users instead of Sessions, then that can be assembled using a custom report (although, like all Users reports, the fields will not add to the total).

Finally, if you want to know exactly which user clicked where, then I'm afraid Google Analytics isn't set up like that, unless you happen to have your users perfectly separated by a different dimension.

Comment: Thank You Mr. Brazier.

" Finally, if you want to know exactly which user clicked where, then I'm afraid Google Analytics isn't set up like that"

this is exactly, what I was also thinking.

Rest, I have already done it exactly how you explained.

thank you so much for your explanation.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Since this post, there's actually been a new feature release that may help you: try Audience>User Explorer

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding it correctly, you want to track your visitors who become your clients or your clients coming through google adwords.
If yes then if you want to use events then you should write your own custom javascript code which will save referrer and landing page location in cookie, then if visitor is currently logged in then make decision if referrer is google and landing page url contains gclid or adid whichever you are using to tag google adwords then you should push an event to google analytics.

Comment: Why would he do that ? Google Analytics already stores campaign information, and if you set up a goal you can map conversions to an advertising channel. That's more or less the whole point of Google Analytics. Can you elaborate how writing additional cookies will help ?